# How do I get the value of MemberInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection

How do I get the value of a `MemberInfo` object? `.Name` returns the name of the variable, but I need the value.

I think you can do this with `FieldInfo` but I don't have a snippet, if you know how to do this can you provide a snippet??

Thanks!

Answer (score 52):

Although I generally agree with Marc's point about not reflecting fields, there are times when it is needed.  If you want to reflect a member and you don't care whether it is a field or a property, you can use this extension method to get the value (if you want the type instead of the value, see nawful's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921608/getting-the-type-of-a-memberinfo-with-reflection)):

```
    public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo memberInfo, object forObject)
    {
        switch (memberInfo.MemberType)
        {
            case MemberTypes.Field:
                return ((FieldInfo)memberInfo).GetValue(forObject);
            case MemberTypes.Property:
                return ((PropertyInfo)memberInfo).GetValue(forObject);
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: much better for me than top answer

Comment: You can also use type switch for this, to simplify
`        switch (memberInfo)
        {
            case FieldInfo fieldInfo:
                return fieldInfo.GetValue(forObject);
            case PropertyInfo propertyInfo:
                return propertyInfo.GetValue(forObject);
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }`
Edit: sorry for ugly formatting

Answer (score 38):

Here's an example for fields, using [FieldInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Test
{
    // public just for the sake of a short example.
    public int x;

    static void Main()
    {
        FieldInfo field = typeof(Test).GetField("x");
        Test t = new Test();
        t.x = 10;

        Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(t));
    }
}
```

Similar code will work for properties using [PropertyInfo.GetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue.aspx) - although there you also need to pass the values for any parameters to the properties. (There won't be any for "normal" C# properties, but C# indexers count as properties too as far as the framework is concerned.) For methods, you'll need to call [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke.aspx) if you want to call the method and use the return value.

Comment: thanks jon -

could you give an example starting with a MemberInfo object though?

Comment: Of what kind? MemberInfos can be properties, fields, methods, events or other types. You can't treat them all the same way.

What would be the "value" of a nested type, for instance? Perhaps you should tell us more about your problem.

Comment: too bad GetValue/SetValue were not an Interface that could be checked against.

Comment: @user295190, **System.Reflection.BindingFlags** `var propeties = MyObject.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.GetProperty & BindingFlags.SetProperty)`

Comment: regarding my now uneditable posted comment.... of course, these are Flag Enumerations that one would use bitwise operators on...

Answer (score 14):

Jon's answer is ideal - just one observation: as part of general design, I would:

1. *generally* avoid reflecting against
   non-public members
2. avoid having public fields (almost always)

The upshot of these two is that *generally* you only need to reflect against public properties (you shouldn't be calling methods unless you know what they do; property getters are *expected* to be idempotent [lazy loading aside]). So for a `PropertyInfo` this is just `prop.GetValue(obj, null);`.

Actually, I'm a big fan of `System.ComponentModel`, so I would be tempted to use:

```
    foreach(PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj));
    }
```

or for a specific property:

```
    PropertyDescriptor prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)["SomeProperty"];
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj));
```

One advantage of `System.ComponentModel` is that it will work with abstracted data models, such as how a `DataView` exposes columns as virtual properties; there are other tricks too (like [performance tricks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HyperPropertyDescriptor.aspx)).

Comment: This proved very effective for my scenario as I have to work with properties and calling GetField() on the object kept returning a null.  Thanks for this.

Comment: ah, there it is.. I could only vaguely recall that another means existed outside of the Reflection namespace: `MemberInfo` and `PropertyInfo`.. `PropertyDescriptor` serves my current purpose well as I'm using `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my instance...