# Getting the type of a MemberInfo with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes, custom-attributes

I'm using reflection to load a treeview with the class structure of a project. Each of the members in a class have a custom attribute assigned to them.

I don't have a problem getting the attributes for a class using `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes()` however I need a way of working out if a class member is a custom class and then needs parsing itself to return the custom attributes.

So far, my code is:

```
MemberInfo[] membersInfo = typeof(Project).GetProperties();

foreach (MemberInfo memberInfo in membersInfo)
{
    foreach (object attribute in memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
    {
        // Get the custom attribute of the class and store on the treeview
        if (attribute is ReportAttribute)
        {
            if (((ReportAttribute)attribute).FriendlyName.Length > 0)
            {
               treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = ((ReportAttribute)attribute).FriendlyName });
            }
        }
        // PROBLEM HERE : I need to work out if the object is a specific type
        //                and then use reflection to get the structure and attributes.
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way of getting the target type of a MemberInfo instance so I can handle it appropriately? I feel I'm missing something obvious but I'm going round in circles at the minute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GetProperties` returns an array of `PropertyInfo` so you should use that.
Then it is simply a matter of using the [`PropertyType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx) property.

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(Project).GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{
    // ...
    if(propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(MyCustomClass))
        // ...
}
```

Comment: yeah, the `MemberInfo[] membersInfo = ` is a bad sign. One of the reasons I like `var`  - less things to get wrong.

Answer (score 74):

I think you can get better performance if you carry around this extension method:

```
public static Type GetUnderlyingType(this MemberInfo member)
{
    switch (member.MemberType)
    {
        case MemberTypes.Event:
            return ((EventInfo)member).EventHandlerType;
        case MemberTypes.Field:
            return ((FieldInfo)member).FieldType;
        case MemberTypes.Method:
            return ((MethodInfo)member).ReturnType;
        case MemberTypes.Property:
            return ((PropertyInfo)member).PropertyType;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException
            (
             "Input MemberInfo must be if type EventInfo, FieldInfo, MethodInfo, or PropertyInfo"
            );
    }
}
```

Should work for any `MemberInfo`, not just `PropertyInfo`. You may avoid `MethodInfo` from that list since its not under lying type per se (but return type).

In your case:

```
foreach (MemberInfo memberInfo in membersInfo)
{
    foreach (object attribute in memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
    {
        if (attribute is ReportAttribute)
        {
            if (((ReportAttribute)attribute).FriendlyName.Length > 0)
            {
               treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = ((ReportAttribute)attribute).FriendlyName });
            }
        }

        //if memberInfo.GetUnderlyingType() == specificType ? proceed...
    }
}
```

I wonder why this hasn't been part of BCL by default.

Comment: I like this! Always felt a bit fishy casting, even when I knew it was a `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: I'm getting an Exception when memberInfo comes from a MemberExpression.Member, it's a Property but it can't be casted

Comment: @Daniel looks like a UnaryExpression stands in between. You will have to type check for UnaryExpression and if so take its Operand property. Better to make it a separate question.