# Getting the source member type

Tags: c#, automapper

How to get the type of the source member when using `ForAllMembers`?

E.g. when doing

```
public MapperConfiguration CreateMapperConfiguration<TSource, TDestination>()
{
    return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>().ForAllMembers(memberOptions =>
        {
            memberOptions.Condition((source, destination, sourceMemberValue, destinationMemberValue, resolutionContext) =>
            {
                if (sourceMemberValue == null)
                {
                    // How to get the type of the source member here?                    
                    // ResolutionContext.SourceType and ResolutionContext.DestinationType don't exist.
                }
                else
                {
                  var type = sourceMemberValue.GetType();

                  // How to find out if the type is a nullable type?
                  // The CLR converts int? to int when the value is boxed
                  // (which happens with sourceMemberValue since its
                  // static type is object).
                }                

                return true;
            });
        });

    });
}
```

Getting the source member type from `ResolutionContext` was possible via `SourceType` property in [version 4](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/v4.2.1/src/AutoMapper/ResolutionContext.cs#L42) but this property doesn't exist anymore.

I checked the [Upgrade guide](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html) but didn't find anything about this breaking change.

`IMemberConfigurationExpression` (received as `memberOptions`) has a `DestinationMember` property (of type `MemberInfo`) so the destination member type is available here (e.g. when casting `MemberInfo` to `PropertyInfo`) but there is no `SourceMember` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absence of `IMemberConfigurationExpression.SourceMember` is indeed felt. This hack relies on the source and destination members having the same name:

```
var sourceMember = typeof(TSource).GetMember(memberOptions.DestinationMember.Name);
```

From there you can [discover its type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16043551/1953590). If you know the member is a property, you can simplify:

```
var sourceProp = typeof(TSource).GetProperty(memberOptions.DestinationMember.Name);
var sourceType = sourceProp?.PropertyType;
```

Then you can [test if it's a `Nullable<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8939958/1953590).