# Sorting a list using reflection to pass a member name by string

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a and `mini` class and a `List<T>` thereof.

```
List<mini> result;

public class mini
{
    public long SN;
    public int PlayTime;
    public string Date;
    public int Score;
}

//The value is the Name of SN, PlayTime, Date, Score
string sortColumn;      
string sortColumnDir;  //asc, desc value
```

The caller can specify a member name to sort on, and I try to sort on the result value:

```
if("SN" == sortColumn)
    var sortresult = result.OrderBy(c => c.SN).ToList<miniCompletion>();
else if("PlayTime" == Date)
    var sortresult = result.OrderBy(c => c.PlayTime).ToList<miniCompletion>();
else if("PlayTime" == sortColumn)
    var sortresult = result.OrderBy(c => c.PlayTime).ToList<miniCompletion>();
else if("Score" == sortColumn)
    var sortresult = result.OrderBy(c => c.Score).ToList<miniCompletion>();
```

But this code is too inefficient, because it involves a lot of copy-pasting nearly duplicate code. And for sorting descendingly, the code doubles in size.

So I tried:

```
var sortresult = result.OrderBy(c => c.GetType().GetMember(sortColumn)[0].Name).ToList();
```

But the sort failed.

Comment: Please define "inefficient" in this context. Your reflection code will take up more run time, not by a lot, but some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your sorting lambda dynamically with linq expressions. Try this code:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(mini), "c");
var member = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, sortColumn);
var cast = Expression.Convert(member, typeof(IComparable));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<mini, IComparable>>(cast, parameter);
```

now `lambda` is an expression like `c => (IComparable)c.Date` and can be compiled to `Func<mini, IComparable>`:

```
var func = lambda.Compile();
```

At this moment you can sort your `result`:

```
var sortedResult = sortColumnDir == "ASC"
    ? result.OrderBy(func)
    : result.OrderByDescending(func);
```

You can find demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5NtdhN)

Please note, that this code is working because all fields in `mini` are implementing IComparable interface

Answer (score 2):

The sort fails because you're sorting by the property *name*, not its value. The name is of course equal for all items.

You need to get the *value*. Use `GetField(...).GetValue(c)`. If you can't use `GetField()` (or you'd rather even use properties, not fields, so `GetProperty()`), see [How do I get the value of MemberInfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238555/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-memberinfo).

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if("SN" == sortColumn) var sortresult = result.OrderBy(c => c.SN).ToList<miniCompletion>(); else if("PlayTime" == Date) var sortresult = result.OrderBy(c => c.PlayTime).ToList<miniCompletion>(); else if("PlayTime" == sortColumn) var sortresult = result.OrderBy(c => c.PlayTime).ToList<miniCompletion>(); else if("Score" == sortColumn) var sortresult = result.OrderBy(c => c.Score).ToList<miniCompletion>();
```

With enums for asc, desc and sortColumn like:

```
If(SortComun.SN == sortColumn)
```

Int comparison is faster and enums are cleaner. Also, you can try result.AsParallel().OrderBy() if you have too much registers.

About your second approach, try:

```
var sortResult = result.OrderBy(c => c.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn).GetValue(c)).ToList();
```

You can test which approach suits you better. Having reflection as the most generic answer, the other one could be faster in an intensive environment.

If you test and share your tests result could be awesome.

Comment: I try
[code]if(sortColumn != null) var num =  result.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn);
but num is null.

Comment: Your third line of code worked nicely for me